# integer or long value that read from database or file become Persian numbers when the input language android device is Farsi?

Tags: android

Why do numbers read from database or file downloaded to phone become Persian numbers when the language is Farsi?
Is there a general solution to this problem?

error :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException
For input string: "۶٫۸۱"
```

in this line :

```
 float twoDigitsF = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(distanceInMeters));
```

my function is :

```
public static float CalculationByDistance(double start_lat, double start_lng, double end_lat, double end_lng) {
        Location loc1 = new Location("");
        loc1.setLatitude(start_lat);
        loc1.setLongitude(start_lng);

        Location loc2 = new Location("");
        loc2.setLatitude(end_lat);
        loc2.setLongitude(end_lng);

        float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        float twoDigitsF = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(distanceInMeters));
        return twoDigitsF;
    }
```

```
the log of distanceInMeters in console is : 6.8146
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to read number from file to calculate distance of two location ,but when input langugae devices is farsi the number will be farsi .for example read ۲۹ instance of 29

Comment: Update your question with your code and your expected output result and also the result you're getting due to the phone language.

Comment: how you check the numbers?

Comment: do you using any persian font in your app?

Comment: i use iransanse font but it happens just when input language is persion

Answer (score 2):

Since your log is printed in English digits, it shows that the culprit is laying behind the `DecimalFormat` no-args constructor which uses the your default app locale as the decimal format locale. In your case you just need to declare your locale preference which is `Locale.ENGLISH` to your `DecimalFormat` constructor so it would be:

```
DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(distanceInMeters);
```

Note that `DecimalFormat.getInstance()` returns a `NumberFormat` instance which does not give you the ability to use your own pattern. Judging by your logged distance and your pattern I can say you're looking for a rounding procedure to reduce your distance floating points by 2. In that case you don't need to convert your number to formatted String and the parsing it back to float which is heavy of course; you just need to use [`round(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)) method from `Math` class with some trick:

```
float twoDigitsF = Math.round(distanceInMeters * 100) / 100f;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to change number format :

```
    private static float getUSNumber(String Numtoconvert){

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    try {
      if(Numtoconvert.contains("٫"))
        Numtoconvert=formatter.parse(Numtoconvert.split("٫")[0].trim())+"."+formatter.parse(Numtoconvert.split("٫")[1].trim());
      else
        Numtoconvert=formatter.parse(Numtoconvert).toString();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Float.valueOf(Numtoconvert);
  }
```

and then :

```
CalculationByDistance(getUSNumber(start_lat), getUSNumber(start_lng), getUSNumber(end_lat), getUSNumber(end_lng));
```

although I think you don't need them and you get number from wrong place!